# The equivalence classes of $N\sim M\Leftrightarrow G/N\cong G/M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, computational-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group.  Given some $N\unlhd G$, define $$\mathfrak{C}_N:=\{M\unlhd G : G/M \cong G/N\}.$$

> 1. How are the subgroups in $\mathfrak{C}_N$ related?  Is there some other description of $\mathfrak{C}_N$?
> 2. Would there be a more direct way to compute this set than computing $G/N$, then computing $G/M$ for every (appropriate order) $M\unlhd G$ and checking for isomorphism?

For an example of what I mean by "more direct," say I wanted all conjugates of some $g\in G$.  I could check each $g^\prime \in G$ to see if there exists an $x$ so that $g^\prime=g^x$, but it would be much easier to just compute $g^x$ for all $x\in G$ (or all $x$ in a transversal of $C_G(g)$ in $G$, if we have that information).  If possible, I'd like to do a similar thing to compute $\mathfrak{C}_N$.

**Motivation:** I am running a computational experiment having to do with [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/267521/12952) (which is becoming somewhat of an obsession) that requires computing the complete partition of the set of normal subgroups of $G$ under $M\sim N \Leftrightarrow M\in \mathfrak{C}_N$.  If $M,N\unlhd G$ are related by an outer automorphism, then surely $M\sim N$, but converse is not necessarily true.  So, we could start by computing $N^{\operatorname{Out}(G)}$ for each $N\unlhd G$, but we would still have to check whether $N\sim M$ between each of those sets, so this is not much of an improvement.

*EDIT*: By the way, if this is too tough for general $G$ as @MartinBrandenburg suggests, I would still be interested to hear an answer for any of the following restricted cases: $p$-groups, nilpotent groups, solvable groups.

Comment: I doubt you can relate the groups in the set very easily. Note for example that all maximal subgroups of a $p$-group will be in such a set together, and they need not be related very much, apart from having the same order.

Comment: Maybe, it would reasonable to consider another problem: when the exact sequences $$0\to M\to G\to G/M$$ and $$0\to N\to G\to G/N$$ are isomorphic (i.e. the corresponding diagram is commutative)?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That's a good point.  I think that for solvable groups one generally computes representatives of conjugacy classes of maximal subgroups by lifting from chief factors.  Maybe something like that could be adapted to this problem.

Comment: This comment is only remotely related to what you are doing, but I thought maybe you might get some inspiration from Reyes' use of "similar right ideals" in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.3701.pdf). Right ideals $A$ and $B$ are similar if $R/A$ and $R/B$ are isomorphic as right $R$ modules. It turns out there are several intersting things you can say about such ideals. Good question btw!

Comment: This is one of the many questions which are quite easy to ask but which have no good answer (at least for general $G$). My advice (and not more): Don't waste your time ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I understand where you might say that about (1), but don't you find (2) interesting?  It seems to me that at least a small improvement ought to be achievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special case of your question that plays an essential role in the [$p$-group generation algorithm](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/pgroup-alg.pdf). It should be Theorem 2.5 there.

Comment: This is very useful.